# cqlsh equivalent to mysql -e

Tags: shell, cassandra, cqlsh

I'm trying to create a small shell script where it would be very handy for me to run a command directly from the command line via cqlsh.

In MySQL I could do something like:

```
mysql -u root  -e "show databases;"
```

Is there a cqlsh equivalent to `-e`, or is the closest equivalent putting whatever commands I want to run in a file and use `-f`?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

For just a one-shot command, `cqlsh` 4.1.1 also has a `-e` option:

```
$cqlsh -e 'desc keyspaces' -u myusername -p mypassword localhost

branch     stackoverflow  products  system_auth  
customers  system         branches  system_traces
```

If you have something complicated, like a multi-line sequence of commands, then the `-f` option on `cqlsh` should be what you want to do.  To demo, I'll create a simple cql script file called `descTables.cql` which looks like this:

```
$ cat descTables.cql
use stackoverflow;
desc tables;
```

Now, I'll invoke that cql script with `cqlsh -f`:

```
$cqlsh -f descTables.cql -u myusername -p mypassword localhost

datasimple  items
```

FYI- It looks like the most-recent version of 2.0 has `cqlsh` 4.1.1, which has the `-e` flag.  On one of my instances, I have 4.1.0 and the `-e` option is not available.

Comment: This makes sense, I'm stuck with cqlsh 3.1.7 for now, but at least I know that the option exists in more recent versions.

Comment: This is done by https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-7172, which is in 2.0.9 and 2.1

Answer (score 0):

There are more options they are listed below:

1. "-C", "--color", action='store_true', dest='color', help='Always use
   color output'
2. "--no-color", action='store_false', dest='color', help='Never use
   color output'
3. "-u", "--username", help="Authenticate as user."
4. "-p", "--password", help="Authenticate using password."
5. '-k', '--keyspace', help='Authenticate to the given keyspace.'
6. "-f", "--file", help="Execute commands from FILE, then exit"
7. "-t", "--transport-factory", help="Use the provided Thrift transport
   factory function."
8. '--debug', action='store_true', help='Show additional debugging
   information'
9. 1. '--cqlversion', default=DEFAULT_CQLVER, help='Specify a particular 
      CQL version (default: %default).'' Examples: "3.0.3", "3.1.0"'